# How to find difference in two not distinct arrays in javascript? I used underscore but I am open to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

If I have two arrays like

```
array1 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}, {id:'id3'}]
array2 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}]
```

The expected result should be `[{id:'id3'}]`

My method works perfectly for distinct arrays.

```
idsFrom1 = _.pluck(array1, 'id');
idsFrom2 = _.pluck(array2, 'id');
var diff = _.difference(_.union(idsFrom1, idsFrom2), _.intersection(idsFrom1, idsFrom2))
```

Comment: What would be result if array2 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id4'}]

Comment: can you confirm if values in your arrays are correct? I took your code and tried with underscore. I had to change `_.diff` to `_.difference` and result was `[]`. Is everything correct?

Comment: My solution is not correct for the example that is given. @codneto. The result should not be []

Comment: what I meant to ask was can arrays have objects with duplicate ids, as in above code array1 has `id3` repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you have to use some mechanism to count the deleted elements, such as `_.countBy`:

```js
var first = [{
  id: 'id1'
}, {
  id: 'id2'
}, {
  id: 'id3'
}, {
  id: 'id3'
}]
var second = [{
  id: 'id1'
}, {
  id: 'id2'
}, {
  id: 'id3'
}]

function unwrap (o) {
  return o[this]
}

function wrap (k) {
  return _.object([k], [String(this)])
}

function counted(array) {
  return _.countBy(array, unwrap, 'id')
}

function constant() {
  return String(this)
}


function difference(first, second) {
  return _.flatten(_.values(_.mapObject(counted(first), function(v, k) {
    return _.range(0, v - this[k]).map(constant, k)
  }, counted(second)))).map(wrap, 'id')
}

console.log(difference(first, second))
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach steps through one of the arrays and removes elements from both arrays that match as it moves through the array. That way anything without a partner in both arrays will remain at the end:

```js
var array1 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}, {id:'id3'}]
var array2 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}]

idsFrom1 = _.pluck(array1, 'id');
idsFrom2 = _.pluck(array2, 'id');

for(var i=0;i<idsFrom1.length;) {
  var index = idsFrom2.indexOf(idsFrom1[i]);
  if(index > -1) {
    idsFrom1.splice(i,1);
    idsFrom2.splice(index,1);
  }
  else i++;
}

diff = [].concat(idsFrom1,idsFrom2);
objarr = [];
for(var i=0;i<diff.length;i++) objarr.push({"id":diff[i]});
console.log(objarr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you don't want to modify your original arrays, then you can create copies and use them for the modification

```js
var array1 = [{
    id: 'id1'
  }, {
    id: 'id2'
  }, {
    id: 'id3'
  }, {
    id: 'id3'
  }],
  array2 = [{
    id: 'id1'
  }, {
    id: 'id2'
  }, {
    id: 'id3'
  }];

_.each(array1, function(obj1, i) {
  _.each(array2, function(obj2, j) {
    // Make sure the objects are not cleared off by a previous comparison
    var isEqual = array1[i] && array2[j] && _.isEqual(obj1, obj2);
    if (isEqual) {
      array1[i] = array2[j] = null;
    }
  });
});

console.log([].concat(_.compact(array1), _.compact(array2)));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The _.union() will remove duplicate members of the array. For example, if the first array contained [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}, {id:'id3'}, {id:'id3'}] (ie: a total of 3 copies of 'id3') then the union would get rid of the extra one and only show 1 of them in the output. You should use [].concat() instead of _.union().

Comment: I tried out your test case and I get 2 copies of `id3`. But I think I understand why it is working and what you are trying to point out. My code is working because we have an array of objects, and `{id: 'id3'} === {id: 'id3'}` returns `false`. But if the arrays were like `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3]` (array of primitives), then my code would output `[3]`. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

This one doesn't use splice() and instead it "marks" each array member that should be removed by setting it to null and then uses compact() to take them all out at once. The speed of the indexOf() actually improves as idsFrom2 gets smaller with splice, so the faster approach depends on the number of matches and sizes of arrays.

```js
array1 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}, {id:'id3'}]
array2 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}]

idsFrom1 = _.pluck(array1, 'id');
idsFrom2 = _.pluck(array2, 'id');

for(var i=0;i<idsFrom1.length;i++) {
  var index = idsFrom2.indexOf(idsFrom1[i]);
  if(index > -1) {
    idsFrom1[i] = null;
    idsFrom2[index] = null;
  }
}
diff = [].concat(_.compact(idsFrom1),_.compact(idsFrom2));
objarr = [];
for(var i=0;i<diff.length;i++) objarr.push({"id":diff[i]});
console.log(objarr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one appears to be the fastest in all of my tests. Use the splice() on the idsFrom2 array to get it to shrink as you move through idsFrom1, and set null on the idsFrom1 array matches and use compact() afterwards.

```js
var array1 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}, {id:'id3'}];
var array2 = [{id: 'id1'}, {id:'id2'}, {id:'id3'}];

idsFrom1 = _.pluck(array1, 'id');
idsFrom2 = _.pluck(array2, 'id');

for(var i=0;i<idsFrom1.length;i++) {
  var index = idsFrom2.indexOf(idsFrom1[i]);
  if(index > -1) {
    idsFrom1[i] = null;
    idsFrom2.splice(index,1);
  }
}
diff = [].concat(_.compact(idsFrom1),idsFrom2);
objarr = [];
for(var i=0;i<diff.length;i++) objarr.push({"id":diff[i]});
console.log(objarr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```